# Nginx + django +nodejs : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: nginx, django, node.js

This is first time using nginx and nodejs. I have two apps one is built using django and other is built using nodejs (expressjs +openvidu). I am trying to configure nginx, django app works fine, I am having trouble with nodejs. nginx is not serving js files. I am getting the below error in console,(I suspect it is because browser is not able to find JavaScript file) both of my js files present under public folder.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Could you also suggest me if this is not the proper way to deploy django and nodejs

Below is my nginx configuration. */meeting* is the node app.

```
 server {

  server_name sophie.ovgu.de;

  location /meeting {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
  location /videoapp {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sophie.ovgu.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sophie.ovgu.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = sophie.ovgu.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name sophie.ovgu.de;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Please note "proxy_pass https://localhost:5000" this should be https as openvidu server requires it. Please refer this [link](https://docs.openvidu.io/en/2.12.0/tutorials/openvidu-hello-world/)

This is my folder structure

```
├───node_modules
├───public
│     app.js
│     openvidu-browser-2.18.0.js   
│───views
        index.ejs
│   openviducert.pem
│   openvidukey.pem
│   package-lock.json
│   package.json
│   README.md
│   server.js
```

This is how I am calling js file in index.html

```
>       <script src="/openvidu-browser-2.18.0.js"></script>
>       <script src="/app.js"></script>
>       <script>
```

Comment: Where is your `root` directive?

Comment: @MichaelHampton its using reverse-proxy for what should a root be used? I bet there is some "<" misspelled

Comment: @djdomi For service of static content. The OP appears to have forgotten to look at the Network tab and see that he has received some 4xx error and checked to see what it was and where it came from.

Comment: I am sorry I am on vacation.  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" is because the browser is not able to find .js file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43781649/7359052)  app.js and openvidu-browser-2.18.0.js in my case.  For some reason it is not able to find javascript file under public folder. The nodeapp is working, if I use it without nginx

Comment: When you return from vacation, go back to read the very first comment.